# Problems with c++ cin

Tags: cin

I am having an issue with the code printing out the next prompt without waiting on an answer for the first prompt. I have tried cin.ignore, endl and cin.clear
I am very new to programming this is only my second semester in college. If this is an obvious answer to you please be gentle with me. This is my first attempt to ask pro's. I usually keep my questions to my class forums.

[This shows the code and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttb9G.jpg)

Comment: **don't post code as screenshots!** - use the edit-function to include it in your original question - **as text**. and take care of proper formatting, select your code and press ctrl+k to automatically mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I found the problem was that I didn't do a getline two prompts up on another string. I got rid of cin.ignore altogether. Thank you all anyway.